# onStop(), onPause(), onCreate(), onResume(), and GPS

Tags: android, gps

I have an app working that is `GPS` based.  It has many activities and all use the `GPS`.  For example, one activity shows the distance to a location, another shows the speed and direction.  I set up and call `requestLocationUpdates()` in `onCreate()` and call `removeUpdates()` in `onPause()`.

This all works but the `GPS` blinks and has to re-acquire when switching activities.  I did a test and if I put the `removeUpdates()` in `onStop()` instead of in `onPause()` there is no blinking.  Apparently `onStop()` is called after the new activity starts which explains the lack of blinking.

I have read the posts on this subject and there seems to be a difference of opinion.  However, it looks like I should use `onStop()` and am wondering if there is any reason I should not.

The second issue is that there is no `onResume()` code so there is no `GPS` after a back-arrow or after turning the screen off and on.  I should fix this.  Right now my `onCreate()` code creates the location manager and basically has all my code in it.  It looks like following the life cycle flow chart that I should move the `removeUpdates()` to onStop and move the creation of the lm and ll to `onStart()`.  Is this correct?

Here is my `onCreate()` code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```

Here is my onPause code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(lm != null) {
            lm.removeUpdates(ll);
        }
        ll = null;
        lm = null;
    }
```

So I think I should just change the onPause() to onStop() and make onStart() this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```

And my onCreate code as this;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  }
```

This said, I am kind of new to all this and this is my first application so I would like to know what I am missing here.

Comment: Why don't you use Service and get Locations whenever you need?

Comment: I should have said that all my activities are GPS activities.  There is no activity where I want the GPS to be off, even sitting on a menu.  The reason I have not gone to a service is that I don't want to query a service and I can't find how to have the service respond with an onChange() like the requestLocationUpdates does.  I mean, isn't the location manager basically a service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done something similar to your app, except that I've delegated the GPS functionality to a service which stops the GPS when no activities are bound to it and starts it when an activity binds to it. I bind to the service in the onStarts and unbind in the onStops. Logging the on.. methods when I switch activities gives a sequence like this:

```
FIRST Activity onCreate
FIRST Activity onStart
FIRST Activity onResume
FIRST Activity onPause
SECOND Activity onCreate
SECOND Activity onStart
SECOND Activity onResume
FIRST Activity onStop
```

If done it via a service so that I've only got one LocationManager to control, you could either take the same approach, or requestUpdates in the onStarts() and remove them in the onStops()

Comment: I appreciate your list of the flow of the activities.  I see from this that the onStart #2 goes before the onStop #1 which is what keeps the GPS light on.  I would use a service if I knew how to have the service push updates to my code the way the LocationManager does.

Comment: Have a study of Ibinder interface for how to pass parameters TO the service from activities. Have the service do sendBroadcast() and have  BroadcastReceivers in the activities pick up the broadcasts. Extras can be passed into the broadcasts, these can send data FROM the service TO the activities.

Comment: I changed all my code to use onStart and onStop and so far so good.  I do want to eventually do GPS logging (saving locations and speed every second) so a service will be required.  It is nice to hear that a service can broadcast and that activities can receive broadcasts as this is an essential part of what I need and makes it worth learning.  Any links to good tutorials are welcome.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd suggest following good read about [location strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

If you just want a one-time location fix you need to make it a bit more independent from the activity life cycle because acquiring the GPS location can take longer than the user switches your activities.

So don't stop the request in onPause or onStop. You could use a special location query handler that lives as a singleton instance in your Application object (create a derivative of Application for that).

Tell that location handler to get a fresh fix if necessary in your activities' onStart or onResume method for example. Let the handler keep the latest and best location data which can be immediately used as needed.

You could query for the first time a NETWORK_PROVIDER location because this should be faster than GPS and you immediately have something to work with even though it's not accurate. On top of that you'd also get a location in case the user turned off the GPS module.

However, that depends on how accurate the result has to be. You could also create a local service that queries the GPS location and waits for its result to come. When the result is there you can notify your currently running activity via a local broadcast intent.

In any case, you can get the last known location with locationManager.getLastKnownLocation

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not 100% what question you're asking here, but I will try to help you out.  `OnPause` is called whenever the Activity loses focus.  This is primarily for popups and such that cause the Activity to be in the background, but blurred.  `OnStop` is called whenever a new activity is started.  You should put your location retrieval code in `OnResume`.  `OnResume` is called any time that the application begins again.  This includes any calls to `OnCreate` or `OnStart`.  You should put your `lm.removeUpdates(ll);` logic in OnStop as well.  This is the generally accept method for location retrieval in a life cycle;  I just ended a sentence with a semicolon... I've been coding too much.